# Replace the value of a variable using SED

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a variable in multiple files that looks like this:

```
localparam SOME_VARIABLE    = 2'h1;  // some comments
```

I'm looking for a way to replace the value of this variable after that 'h'. For example in this case I want to search for "SOME_VARIABLE" pattern and change its value after h (1 in this case but might be something else) to 0 using SED. Note the space between the name of the variable and the = sign might vary and I want to keep it as it is, I only need to change that number after h.

I know how to find the line that matches a pattern and replace it by another value but I want to keep it as it is and replace only the number after h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `;` can occur only once before possible `;` in comments

```
$ echo "localparam SOME_VARIABLE    = 2'h1;  // some 23; comments" | sed '/SOME_VARIABLE/ s/[0-9]*;/0;/'
localparam SOME_VARIABLE    = 2'h0;  // some 23; comments
```

- `/SOME_VARIABLE/` line to match
- `s/[0-9]*;/0;/` replace first occurrence of numbers followed by `;` to `0;`

  - If there can be space between number and `;` use `[0-9 ]*` or `[0-9 \t]*` as needed

Comment: I don't want to look for first occurrence for numbers. I don't want to replace that 2, only the value after h

Comment: this will replace only the number after `h` as shown... number before `h` won't have `;`

Comment: How can I cover the possibility when after that number (that I want to change) is `,` instead of `;` Can I cover both possibilities with only one command?

Comment: just change `;` to `,`.. if either of them can be present, you need to [capture and backreference](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution/8893/backreference#t=201704040144098345819) ... something like `s/[0-9]*\([,;]\)/0\1/`

Comment: At the end I end up with: `sed '/SOME_VARIABLE/ s/h[0-9]/h0/'` This works with all the files that I want to change (I replace only the number after h, withouth the `;` or `,`)

Comment: good to know you found your own way :) that solution assumes that there won't be any match of `h` followed by digit anywhere before in the line, which is rather stringent requirement..

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ cat f
localparam SOME_VARIABLE    = 2'h1;  // some comments

$ awk '{gsub(/[[:digit:]]*;/,"5;");print}' f
localparam SOME_VARIABLE    = 2'h5;  // some comments

$  awk '{gsub(/[[:digit:]]*;/,"0;");print}' f
localparam SOME_VARIABLE    = 2'h0;  // some comments
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple approach using sed:

```
sed '/SOME_VARIABLE/s/[0-9];/0;/'  file
```